# Multipart File Upload on Google Appengine using jersey-1.7

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jersey

I wrote an application on Google Appengine with Jersey to handle simple file uploading. This works fine when it was on jersey 1.2. In the later versions (current 1.7) @FormDataParam is introduced to handle multipart/form inputs. I am using jersey-multipart and the mimepull dependency. It seems that the new way of doing it is creating temporary files in appengine which we all know is illegal...

Am I missing something or doing something wrong here since Jersey is now supposedly compatible with AppEngine?

```
@POST 
@Path("upload") 
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA) 
public void upload(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream in) { .... }
```

The above will fail when called with these exceptions...

```
/upload
java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to create temporary file
    at java.io.File.checkAndCreate(File.java:1778)
    at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:1870)
    at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:1907)
    at org.jvnet.mimepull.MemoryData.createNext(MemoryData.java:87)
    at org.jvnet.mimepull.Chunk.createNext(Chunk.java:59)
    at org.jvnet.mimepull.DataHead.addBody(DataHead.java:82)
    at org.jvnet.mimepull.MIMEPart.addBody(MIMEPart.java:192)
    at org.jvnet.mimepull.MIMEMessage.makeProgress(MIMEMessage.java:235)
    at org.jvnet.mimepull.MIMEMessage.parseAll(MIMEMessage.java:176)
    at org.jvnet.mimepull.MIMEMessage.getAttachments(MIMEMessage.java:101)
    at com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.MultiPartReaderClientSide.readMultiPart(MultiPartReaderClientSide.java:177)
    at com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.MultiPartReaderServerSide.readMultiPart(MultiPartReaderServerSide.java:80)
    at com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.MultiPartReaderClientSide.readFrom(MultiPartReaderClientSide.java:139)
    at com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.MultiPartReaderClientSide.readFrom(MultiPartReaderClientSide.java:77)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.getEntity(ContainerRequest.java:474)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.getEntity(ContainerRequest.java:538)
```

Anyone have a clue? Is there a way to do thing while preventing mimepull from creating the temporary file?

Answer (score 17):

For files beyond its default size, `multipart` will create a temporary file. To avoid this — creating a file is impossible on gae — you can create a `jersey-multipart-config.properties` file in the project's resources folder and add this line to it:

```
bufferThreshold = -1
```

Then, the code is the one you gave:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response post(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream stream, @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition disposition) throws IOException {
  post(file, disposition.getFileName());
  return Response.ok().build();
}
```

Comment: Any idea how to do this programmatically?

Comment: @gk5885 By "programmatically" you mean without Jersey/JAX-RS?

Comment: I mean how to set the bufferThrehold in code rather than via a properties file.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Just an FYI, if you're using Jersey 2+ you need to use `jersey.config.multipart.bufferThreshold` as your property name.

Comment: Can you please help me with where the `resources` folder should be. Is it in `\war` or `\WEB-INF` or somewhere else? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot , this has made my day ... I was struggling with this issue for quite some time. Thanks a lot again

Comment: This seems like the answer

Comment: Is there any way to set a file size limit ?

Answer (score 11):

For the benefit of those struggling when using Eclipse with GPE (Google Plugin for Eclipse) I give this slightly modified solution derived from @yves' answer.

I have tested it with `App Engine SDK 1.9.10` and `Jersey 2.12`. **It will not work with `App Engine SDK 1.9.6 -> 1.9.9` amongst others due to a different issue.**

Under your `\war\WEB-INF\classes` folder create a new file called `jersey-multipart-config.properties`. Edit the file so it contains the line `jersey.config.multipart.bufferThreshold = -1`.

**Note** that the `\classes` folder is hidden in Eclipse so look for the folder in your operating system's file explorer (e.g. Windows Explorer).

Now, both when the `multipart` feature gets initialized (on Jersey servlet initialization) and when a file upload is done (on Jersey servlet post request) the temp file will not be created anymore and GAE won't complain.

Comment: Thanks man! `jersey.config.multipart.` before the `bufferThreshold` fixed it! ;)

Comment: For anyone wanting to do this in eclipse: Yes, the `classes` folder doesn't show up in the Package Explorer view, but you can still access it by using the _Navigator_ view instead of _Package Explorer_. (From there, you could even right-click and do "Show in Remote Systems view" if you wanted to explore the underlying file system.)

Comment: You got Jersey 2 working with App Engine? I thought it depended on servlet-api:1.3.x. I know this is super old, but I'd be interested to see your dependency tree...

Answer (score 3):

It is very important to put the file `jersey-multipart-config.properties` under `WEB-INF/classes` inside the WAR.

Usually in a WAR file structure you put the config files (`web.xml`, `appengine-web.xml`) into `WEB-INF/`, but here you need to put into `WEB-INF/classes`.

Example Maven configuration:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                    </resource>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                        <targetPath>WEB-INF/classes</targetPath>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

And your project structure can look like:

[image: Project Structure]

Content of `jersey-multipart-config.properties` with Jersey 2.x:

```
jersey.config.multipart.bufferThreshold = -1
```

Answer (score 1):

i've found solution to programmatically avoid to use temporary file creation (very useful for GAE implementation)

My solution consist of creating a new MultiPartReader Provider ... below my code

---

```
  @Provider
    @Consumes("multipart/*")
    public class GaeMultiPartReader implements MessageBodyReader<MultiPart> {

    final Log logger = org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    private final Providers providers;

    private final CloseableService closeableService;

    private final MIMEConfig mimeConfig;

    private String getFixedHeaderValue(Header h) {
        String result = h.getValue();

        if (h.getName().equals("Content-Disposition") && (result.indexOf("filename=") != -1)) {
            try {
                result = new String(result.getBytes(), "utf8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {            
                final String msg = "Can't convert header \"Content-Disposition\" to UTF8 format.";
                logger.error(msg,e);
                throw new RuntimeException(msg);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    public GaeMultiPartReader(@Context Providers providers, @Context MultiPartConfig config,
        @Context CloseableService closeableService) {
        this.providers = providers;

        if (config == null) {
            final String msg = "The MultiPartConfig instance we expected is not present. "
                + "Have you registered the MultiPartConfigProvider class?";
            logger.error( msg );
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(msg);
        }
        this.closeableService = closeableService;

        mimeConfig = new MIMEConfig();
        //mimeConfig.setMemoryThreshold(config.getBufferThreshold());
        mimeConfig.setMemoryThreshold(-1L); // GAE FIX
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isReadable(Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return MultiPart.class.isAssignableFrom(type);
    }

    @Override
    public MultiPart readFrom(Class<MultiPart> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType,
        MultivaluedMap<String, String> headers, InputStream stream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        try {
            MIMEMessage mm = new MIMEMessage(stream, mediaType.getParameters().get("boundary"), mimeConfig);

            boolean formData = false;
            MultiPart multiPart = null;

            if (MediaTypes.typeEquals(mediaType, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE)) {
                multiPart = new FormDataMultiPart();
                formData = true;
            } else {
                multiPart = new MultiPart();
            }

            multiPart.setProviders(providers);

            if (!formData) {
                multiPart.setMediaType(mediaType);
            }

            for (MIMEPart mp : mm.getAttachments()) {
                BodyPart bodyPart = null;

                if (formData) {
                    bodyPart = new FormDataBodyPart();
                } else {
                    bodyPart = new BodyPart();
                }

                bodyPart.setProviders(providers);

                for (Header h : mp.getAllHeaders()) {
                    bodyPart.getHeaders().add(h.getName(), getFixedHeaderValue(h));
                }

                try {
                    String contentType = bodyPart.getHeaders().getFirst("Content-Type");

                    if (contentType != null) {
                        bodyPart.setMediaType(MediaType.valueOf(contentType));
                    }

                    bodyPart.getContentDisposition();
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
                    logger.error( "readFrom error", ex );
                    throw new WebApplicationException(ex, 400);
                }

                bodyPart.setEntity(new BodyPartEntity(mp));
                multiPart.getBodyParts().add(bodyPart);
            }

            if (closeableService != null) {
                closeableService.add(multiPart);
            }

            return multiPart;
        } catch (MIMEParsingException ex) {
            logger.error( "readFrom error", ex );
            throw new WebApplicationException(ex, 400);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

We experienced a similar problem, Jetty wouldn't let us upload files more than 9194 bytes, (all of a sudden - one day), we realised afterwards that someone had taken our user access from /tmp, which corresponds to java.io.tmpdir on some linux versions, so Jetty couldn't store the uploaded file there, and we got a 400 error.