# Am I closing my input stream correctly in Java?

Tags: java, jersey, inputstream, dropwizard

I created a class that extends InputStream so that I can keep count of the number of bytes being read and throw an exception if it exceeds a max limit that I define.

Here is my class:

```
    public class LimitedSizeInputStream extends InputStream
    {

        private final InputStream original;
        private final long maxSize;
        private long total;

        public LimitedSizeInputStream(InputStream original, long maxSize)
        {
            this.original = original;
            this.maxSize = maxSize;
        }

        @Override
        public int read() throws IOException
        {
            int i = original.read();
            if (i >= 0)
            {
                incrementCounter(1);
            }
            return i;
        }

        @Override
        public int read(byte b[]) throws IOException
        {
            return read(b, 0, b.length);
        }

        @Override
        public int read(byte b[], int off, int len) throws IOException
        {
            int i = original.read(b, off, len);
            if (i >= 0)
            {
                incrementCounter(i);
            }
            return i;
        }

        private void incrementCounter(int size) throws IOException
        {
            total += size;
            if (total > maxSize)
            {
                throw new IOException("InputStream exceeded maximum size in bytes.");
            }
        }
    }
```

This is coming from: [Copy InputStream, abort operation if size exceeds limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15445504/copy-inputstream-abort-operation-if-size-exceeds-limit/30072143#30072143), I am implementing a Jersey API that needs to fail if a user is uploading a file that is too large.

Here is my resource class:

```
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Path("/test")
    public Response load(
        @Context HttpServletRequest request,
        @FormDataParam(FILE_FIELD) FormDataBodyPart file)
    {
      if (request.getContentLength() > MAX_FILE_SIZE_IN_BYTES)
        {
            // fail fast handle failure
        }

      try (InputStream stream = new LimitedSizeInputStream(
           file.getValueAs(InputStream.class), MAX_FILE_SIZE_IN_BYTES))
        {
            // some logic
        }
      catch (IOException e)
        {
            // handle failure
        }
}
```

I wrapped LimitedSizeInputStream in my try resource so I think the stream should close properly. I'm just a bit confused as to whether the close is handled correctly or if I'm technically opening two input streams through LimitedSizeInputStream and file.getValueAs(InputStream.class) and only one is closing?

Comment: It looks like you implemented something similar to apache commons BoundedInputStream. You might look at their implementation for guidance at least.

Comment: @Deadron similar but not the same. BoundedInputStream doesn't throw an error it just stops reading further

Comment: You should have extended `FilterInputStream`. Don't repost questions here.

Answer (score 3):

The try-with-resources only closes the declared resource. So will only close `metadataStream`.

You should implement the `close` method in `LimitedSizeInputStream` to close the original stream.

```
@Override
public void close() throws IOException {
    original.close();
}
```

Comment: oh ok... that's not good. is there an elegant way to close both without making the code messy?

Comment: I added the required code. That's not messy. If you use an inner input stream, to delegate read calls, it's normal to also delegate the close call.

Comment: but won't that change the behavior so only the inner input stream is closed now and not the LimitedSizeInputStream?

Comment: The purpose of the `close` method is to release any system resources. The only resource that `LimitedSizeInputStream` uses is the underlying  original `InputStream`

Answer (score 1):

If `LimitedSizeInputStream` extends `InputStream` and wraps another stream, then @areus's solution is the best one.

An alternative approach would be to extend `FilterInputStream`, like this:

```
public class LimitedSizeInputStream extends FilterInputStream
{
    private final long maxSize;
    private long total;

    public LimitedSizeInputStream(InputStream original, long maxSize)
    {
        super(original);
        this.original = original;
        this.maxSize = maxSize;
    }

    // use 'this.in' instead of 'this.original'
    // at least one of the 'read' methods needs to be overridden.
}
```

Note that `FilterInputStream` provides default implementations of the API methods that may prove useful.

The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilterInputStream.html) provides details of what the default method implementations do.

Comment: If I override close method and only close the inner stream, how does the LimitedSizeInputStream close?

Comment: You don't need to override close if you use this approach.  The inherited `FilterInputStream:close` method closes `in`.  That is the only thing that actually needs to be closed.

Comment: Another way of looking at this is that your override `close()` closes the `LimitedSizeInputStream`. The purpose of `close` is to release any resources.  The only resource that belongs to your custom stream is the `original` stream that it wraps.  It makes no difference if you close it directly, or get the superclass to close it by delegating via `super.close()`.