# How to get size of file in rest api jersey

Tags: java, rest, jersey, multipartform-data

I have made a rest api in this it is working fine but i want to read size of file and i have used below code to read size of file

```
@POST
@Path("/test")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response upload( FormDataMultiPart form ){
    System.out.println(" size of file="+ filePart.getContentDisposition().getSize());
}
```

but i got the size of file -1 .

Can any one suggest me how can i read actual size of file .

But using

```
System.out.println(" data name ="+ filePart.getContentDisposition().getFileName());
```

i got correct name of file .

Comment: Inject `HttpServletRequest` in your method using `@Context HttpServletRequest request` and try `request.getContentLength()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this is what you wanted. I have verified it in my system. This prints the size of the file in bytes.

```
@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadFile(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream, @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {

    String uploadedFileLocation = "/home/Desktop/" + fileDetail.getFileName();
    // save it
    writeToFile(uploadedInputStream, uploadedFileLocation);
    File file = new File(uploadedFileLocation);
    System.out.println(file.length() + " in bytes");
    String output = "File uploaded to : " + uploadedFileLocation;
    return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
}

// save uploaded file to new location
private void writeToFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream, String uploadedFileLocation) {

    try {
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
        while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            out.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

make sure you have the following dependency in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>2.13</version>
</dependency>
```

also add this to your application class which extends resource config. This registers your class with jersey as having multipart content.

```
super(YourClass.class, MultiPartFeature.class);
```

Comment: With your solution you have to write the stream to file before you can determine the size. The challenge here is of course to know the uploaded size before having to go through the entire stream.

Comment: How about checking size on each byte received?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I think the best way to restrict data size is setting on the server configuration. Please see the related [ref.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091428/setting-file-size-restrictions-when-uploading-files-with-jersey)

Secondly, since it comes with the Stream, it goes til to meet EOF or similar one. That means you cannot find the size at the first place.

Third, however, one of the alternative way for judging size in jersey is using the contents size of the HTTP header. The server gets 'Content-Length' header at the first place to know the size of the body.  `@Context HttpServletRequest request` has `request.getContentLength()` method. But since it has multiparts, you need to be careful that the body size has sum of the data with protocol overheads (seperator/contents infos)

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Try using [HttpServletRequest](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) . Kindly see the docs for more details.

```
   @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response putFile(@Context HttpServletRequest request){
      Part part = request.getPart("filename");
      long fileSize = part.getSize();
    }
```