# Jersey 2.3.1 on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, jersey-2.0

I wonder if last version of Jersey does have support of Google App Engine.
I have found 'gae-integration' project (https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/incubator/gae-integration) with a link to Jersey 2.3.1. Actually all my attempts failed but maybe someone was luckier?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have used Jersey 1.16 before with GAE and it worked fine. Are you saying that the latest version is incompatible with GAE ?

Comment: Atleast I have issues... I've a project with 1.15 and everything is ok, but starting 2.0 Jersey introduce a lot of changes...
I would really appreciate a link on a small demo with 2.3.1 playing with GAE

Comment: May I suggest using Cloud Endpoints for REST instead of Jersey .. I currently use it and it's nice IMO. I do not know may be if you try it it would save you time trying to fix Jersey.

Comment: Any progress with Jersey 2 on GAE? I also ran into problems and the only thing I could find were tutorials for Jersey 1.17. ... I do not want to use Cloud Endpoints (due to portability concerns).

Comment: I struggled to get Jersey 2 to work with GAE but figured it out now. Tested OK with `GAE SDK 1.9.10` and `Jersey 2.12` See for instance this link `http://blog.dejavu.sk/2013/11/19/registering-resources-and-providers-in-jersey-2/`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I struggled to get Jersey 2 to work with GAE but figured it out now.

Tested OK with `GAE SDK 1.9.10` and `Jersey 2.12`, including `multipart/form-data`. See for instance this [blog article](http://blog.dejavu.sk/2013/11/19/registering-resources-and-providers-in-jersey-2/).

In Jersey 2 you have to enable features in your `web.xml` which is automatically enabled in Jersey 1. For example the snippet below enables `JSP` page support and the `multipart/form-data` MIME type features. (I don't think the `GaeFeature` is required, but haven't tested without it).

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>com.namibiaonthenet.www</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.namibiaonthenet.www</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.glassfish.jersey.server.mvc.jsp.JspMvcFeature;
            org.glassfish.jersey.server.gae.GaeFeature;
            org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature;
         </param-value>
    </init-param>

   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> 
</servlet>
```

To enable the `multipart/form-data` feature an additional short config. file is required in your project - for details see my and @yves' answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301973/multipart-file-upload-on-google-appengine-using-jersey-1-7/25848569#25848569).

If you still struggle, let me know in a comment to this answer.