# Using GAE and Jersey with multipart/form-data feature enabled crashes servlet on strartup

Tags: google-app-engine, jersey, multipartform-data

I am using GAE 1.9.10 and Jersey 2.12.

I enable the `multipart/form-data` feature in my `web.xml` as follows

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
    <param-value>
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.mvc.jsp.JspMvcFeature;
        org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature
     </param-value>
</init-param>
```

The web pages loads perfectly on my local dev server including the `multipart` feature, but when I  upload to `xxx.appspot.com` and request any page going through the Jersey servlet I immediately get the following error in my logs (and I get an Http error 500 on the web page):

```
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: A MultiException has 3 exceptions.  They are:
1. java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to create temporary file
2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: create on org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.internal.MultiPartReaderServerSide
3. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: create on org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory

    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.makeUnavailable(ServletHolder.java:415)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:458)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:263)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:199)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:174)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:134)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:446)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:438)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:445)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:220)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:309)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:301)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:442)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

I know that GAE does not allow creation of files so clearly that is where the issue lies (as can be seen from the error above), but I do not know how to resolve this.

Does anyone know a solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To enable the `multipart/form-data` feature on App Engine an additional short config. file is required in your project - for details see my and @yves' answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301973/multipart-file-upload-on-google-appengine-using-jersey-1-7/25848569#25848569).