# MIME****.tmp file creation in Jersey Restful API

Tags: rest, jersey

I created a RESTfule webservice using Jersey2.0 API, which can produce and consume json MediaType.

```
@Path( "/PortfolioSummary" )

public class RESTWSService    
{

    public RESTWSService()
    {

    }

    @POST
    @Consumes( { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON } )
    @Produces( { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON } )
    public String getportfolioSummary( String req )
    {
         ----
    }
}
```

When I deploy the service or invoke the service, temp file like MIME43756487865.tmp is created in my `AppData/local/Temp` folder.

How to avoid this MIME****.tmp file creation in `/Temp` folder?

Comment: See https://www.java.net/forum/topic/glassfish/metro-and-jaxb/mtom-and-temporary-files and https://java.net/jira/browse/MIMEPULL-2 and https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2515

Comment: Hi., Thanks., in of the links it is mentioned as Jersy1.19 has resolved in this issue., I tried using Jersy1.19 jars, still those MIME***.tmp file generated and getting deleted. Kindly help me to resolve this.

Comment: Please try with latest Jersy 2.18

Comment: I have the same problem now. How to avoid these files. Ours is a huge application and upgrading to latest version is not an option for us.

Comment: Probably this may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301973/multipart-file-upload-on-google-appengine-using-jersey-1-7