# MIME*.tmp file are created in %temp% folder

Tags: java, soap, jboss, wildfly, mime

We are using WildFly and JBoss for Java Web api deployment.

We are using SOAP.

When we are hitting the api with small size request (less than 0.5 MB)
MIME*.tmp file is not getting created.

When the request size is bigger (2.5 MB request) the MIME*.tmp file is getting created.

We are also not able to delete these MIME*.tmp file.
When we try it says,

```
The action can't be completed because the file is open in OpenJDK platform binary.
```

These MIME file contain the request as SOAP Envelope in it.

Due to increasing these temp file, our system is getting full.

JBoss Module version 1.9.1 
WildFly version 17.0.1

Answer (score 0):

probably a duplicate of
[MIME****.tmp file creation in Jersey Restful API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31025148/mime-tmp-file-creation-in-jersey-restful-api)

Sounds like it might be an issue with Mimepull.
https://github.com/javaee/metro-mimepull/issues/2
Or maybe Jersey:
https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/issues/2787